# Svg base64 string conversion to Png

Tags: php, svg, png, base64, imagick

I have a **PHP** application that display **images** with **base64 SVG** strings, like so:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"/>
```

I would need to output and display **PNG** files instead.
I have **Imagick** installed and ready, but how can I convert a base64 SVG string to a PNG file?

Comment: Cant't you simply convert base64 to normal svg using base64_decode and then feed the svg image to imagic?

Comment: @Nikolay Seems like you're right, thank you!